# Trouble installing PostGIS PlugIn for OpenJump

Tags: postgis, plugins, openjump

I’m trying to install PostGISPlugin version 1.52 in OpenJUMP 1.7.1 release 4004. I moved the JAR file into my installation’s lib/ext directory, but I’m not sure how to access the plugin-specific UI components. I’m not even sure it’s been properly installed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: OpenJUMP has nowadays r/w PostGIS driver by default and no additional plugins are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJUMP has since version 1.6 a read/write support for PostGIS out-of-the-box without a need to install an additional plugin. This German tutorial is still up-to-date for the current OpenJUMP version 1.7.1 http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jump-pilot/Documentation/OpenJUMP%201.6%20Docs/PostGIS_Tutorial_20.pdf. Tutorial has lots of screen captures so the language should not be any problem.